# How do I get masonry to run again once twitter widgets have rendered?

Tags: views

I am using the [Masonry API](https://www.drupal.org/project/masonry) and [Masonry Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/masonry_views) modules to get a view to render nicely, it works well.

I'm using [oEmbed Core](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed) to render the URL provided by the user into an embedded tweet for a specific node type.  That also works fine.

When the tweet shows up in the view however, my blocks get overlapped because the twitter widget is rendering *after* masonry has run.  How do I rerun masonry once the tweet has fully rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the twitter documentation and found a way to call functions on twitter widget events:

```
// Load the twitter widgets script
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

// Bind an event to rerun the masonry layout when a tweet is rendered
twttr.ready(
  function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind(
      'rendered',
      function (event) {
        jQuery(function($) {
          $('.view-content.masonry').masonry();
        });
      }
    );
  }
);
```